# Adding a form to foreach in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add a form foreach item in a list but when I add the form...the data is not not getting wrapped. The form gets created but then just closes the right away. This is what my foreach looks like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ReplaceEmployeeDocument", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "replace-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("doc", item)
                <div id="replace-document" style="display: none; background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
                    <h3><u>Replace Employee Document</u></h3>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                @Html.Label("File"):
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type='file' name='fuDocument' id='fuDocument' class="form-control" style="height: 40px;" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="Replace" />
                </div>
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
        </td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CompanyNumber)
        <td><a href="@item.FullUrl">View</a> | <a id="replace-button">Replace</a> | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmployeeDocument", new { fileName = item.FullUrl, employeeNo = item.EmployeeNumber })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is what my action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReplaceEmployeeDocument(HttpPostedFileBase fuDocument, Models.EmployeeDocument doc)
{
}
```

This is what the rendered view looks like:

```
<table id="results-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <u>Title</u>
            </th>
            <th>
                <u>Document Type</u>
            </th>
            <th>
                <u>Created By</u>
            </th>
            <th>
                <u>Created Date</u>
            </th>
            <th style="width: 180px;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <form action="/Employee/ReplaceEmployeeDocument" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="replace-form" method="post" style="padding-top: 5px; margin-top: 0px;">
        </form>                        
        <tr>
            <td>
                Mark Has Same File
            </td>
            <td>
                Green Sheet
            </td>
            <td>
                AJOHNSON
            </td>
            <td>
                10/24/2014 12:53:53 PM
            </td>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EmployeeNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The EmployeeNumber field is required." id="item_EmployeeNumber" name="item.EmployeeNumber" type="hidden" value="3077">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CompanyNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The CompanyNumber field is required." id="item_CompanyNumber" name="item.CompanyNumber" type="hidden" value="1">
            <td><a href="http://svr-corpsp1/app/employee/Employee Master Documents/3077_UPDATE.sql">View</a> | <a id="replace-button">Replace</a> | <a href="/Employee/DeleteEmployeeDocument?fileName=http%3A%2F%2Fsvr-corpsp1%2Fapp%2Femployee%2FEmployee%20Master%20Documents%2F3077_UPDATE.sql&amp;employeeNo=3077">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <form action="/Employee/ReplaceEmployeeDocument" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="replace-form" method="post" style="padding-top: 5px; margin-top: 0px;">
        </form>                        
        <tr>
            <td id="replace-document" style="display: none;background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
                <h3><u>Replace Employee Document</u></h3>
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            <label for="File">File</label>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="fuDocument" id="fuDocument" class="form-control" style="height: 40px;">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <input type="submit" value="Replace">
            </td>
            <td>
                Another Test
            </td>
            <td>
                Other
            </td>
            <td>
                AJOHNSON
            </td>
            <td>
                10/24/2014 3:24:18 PM
            </td>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EmployeeNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The EmployeeNumber field is required." id="item_EmployeeNumber" name="item.EmployeeNumber" type="hidden" value="3077">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CompanyNumber must be a number." data-val-required="The CompanyNumber field is required." id="item_CompanyNumber" name="item.CompanyNumber" type="hidden" value="1">
            <td><a href="http://svr-corpsp1/app/employee/Employee Master Documents/3077_1920x1200-Crimson.jpg">View</a> | <a id="replace-button">Replace</a> | <a href="/Employee/DeleteEmployeeDocument?fileName=http%3A%2F%2Fsvr-corpsp1%2Fapp%2Femployee%2FEmployee%20Master%20Documents%2F3077_1920x1200-Crimson.jpg&amp;employeeNo=3077">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Most current:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="display: none;">
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("ReplaceEmployeeDocument", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "replace-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
                            {
                                @Html.Hidden("doc", (EmployeeDocument) item)
                                <div id="replace-document" style="display: none; background-color: white; padding: 15px;">
                                    <h3><u>Replace Employee Document</u></h3>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                @Html.Label("File"):
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type='file' name='fuDocument' id='fuDocument' class="form-control" style="height: 40px;" />
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Replace" />
                                </div>
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
                        </td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeNumber)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.CompanyNumber)
                        <td><a href="@item.FullUrl">View</a> | <a id="replace-button">Replace</a> | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEmployeeDocument", new { fileName = item.FullUrl, employeeNo = item.EmployeeNumber })</td>
                    </tr>

                }
```

Comment: The razor view is almost certainly rendering correctly, however you r code would render invalid HTML, you can't wrap a table row in a form e.g.`<form><tr>...</tr></form>` is not valid, and what you have posted as the "rendered view" looks like the browser trying to make the best of a bad job.

Comment: How else could I do it? Could I wrap the td's?

Comment: You would have to wrap the whole table.

Comment: That would only give me one single form though. Wouldn't it?

Comment: You will get as many forms as you need, but you will also have to have many tables. The only way to have a single table containing mutiple forms is to put each form in it's own `<td></td>`.  This is not specific to forms, the only things making up a table can be table elements, everything else either has to sit outside the table or in a cell.

Comment: I added a new portion to my post. Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: Yes that should render valid html.

Comment: Ya it does but for some reason it is not posting.....when i click the submit button...nothing happens.

Comment: The `submit` button is inside a hidden `td` so its not even visible - what submit button are you talking about? And what do you think `@Html.Hidden("doc", (EmployeeDocument) item)` does? (it certainly wont post back to any parameter in your action method - I suggest you inspect the html it renders). And whats the point of rendering hidden elements outside the form? And then of course there are all the duplicate ID attributes you are rendering. Nothing you are doing makes any sense.